# How to set a value for a target element using Datatable LazyLoading

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to set something like this in the LazyLoading Datatable , I am not able to use the below code.

```
<p:dataTable var="studyPlanList" value="#{editBean.lazyModel}"
                paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{editBean.selectedStudyPlan}"
                id="studyPlanTable">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editBean.onRowSelect}" update=":studyPlanEditForm:display"  >
            </p:ajax> 
            <p:column headerText="StudyPlan" sortBy="#{studyPlanList.name}" filterBy="#{studyPlanList.name}">
            <h:outputText value="#{studyPlanList.name}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Instead of p:column , if it is h:link it is working, I want to achieve similar results;Please Help.

Comment: Hi  Matt Handy , Have posted the table Code. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the facelet tag documentation on `f:setPropertyActionListener`:

> Register an ActionListener instance on the UIComponent associated with
>   the closest parent UIComponent custom action

So you need a triggering action to make it work. This could be a `h:commandButton` or `h:commandLink`. Here is a quick example:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{editBean.submitAction}" value="Select">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{editBean.name}" 
                                 value="#{studyPlanList.name}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Since you are using Primefaces, you could take a look at the row selection feature of `p:dataTable`. Here is an [example from the showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf).

**UPDATE:**

The type of the selection should be the same as the type of your row element. I see from your code that `selection="#{editBean.selectedStudyPlan.name}"` but it should be

```html
selection="#{editBean.selectedStudyPlan}"
```

Comment: Hi I tried to give like this but I am not getting the value as null for the variable studyPlanList that I am using.<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editBean.onRowSelect(studyPlanList)}" update=":studyPlanEditForm:display"> PLEASE HELP.
   </p:ajax>

Comment: If you are using the row selection feature as described in the showcase, you don't need this event listener (the listener method signature is wrong). The selected row is automatically set to the field that you specify in your `selection` attribute of `<p:dataTable>`

Comment: Hi, Ok. But that object is reflecting as null in the Managed bean where as there is actual value displayed in the row.

Comment: Could you please add the complete table (use the "edit" link below your question).

Comment: Hi , Sorry It is still not working.I have updated the code also.I want those value in the managed bean.Please Help.

Comment: Did you verify with a debugger that your ajax rowselect action is called?

Comment: yes It is printing the value as null.But I need the value of the studyplanCategorey object it is printing like this.Value of selectedStudyPlan...................null

Comment: Hi It now works for me. the problem was that in the onRowSelect method inside managed bean I was using the line this.selectedStudyPlan=selectedStudyPlan where it was not needed I think. Thanks.